# Tele-Monitoring SCADA using Android App

Tags: android, scada

I'm planning on develop an android app that can access an HMI/SCADA system, so users of this app could remotely monitor and control their plants using tablets. This is actually an idea for a graduation project.

I've got some experience with SCADA systems and almost no experience with App developing.

My questions are:

1. Firstly, is it possible to implement this idea?
2. What kind of communications between PC and Tablet should I use? Through internet or LAN?
3. Is it necessarily to use OPC? (I've googled and it seemed to be the only way. Even teslaScada app is using it)..
4. And finally, what would be the idea for getting data from the HMI/SCADA?

I only need someone to help me getting my foot at the beginning of right road, to know which topics I should search and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Of course, connecting an electronic system with another one [is possible](http://www.bash.org/?5804). However, it may not be *easy*, especially if you have no experience in network applications.
2. There is no fundamental difference between the Internet and a LAN. You must consider security (and be aware of [pitfalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)). Also, to make your application available via the Internet, you'll have to have a domain name and/or static IP address.
3. You can use any protocol. Typically, most applications use HTTP because it is well-understood, scalable, available on virtually all platforms and it is somewhat known how to secure it. None of this applies to [OPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_for_process_control). To answer the letter of the question, it is not necessary; you can use any protocol.
4. Well, via what protocol do you get the data now (in your current CLI or GUI application)?  That should be (after careful security considerations) a good starting point.

Comment: I'm afraid that I didn't get your last question. However, if you meant which protocol I'm using to link the SCADA GUI to PLCs, then it's SIMPPI. But if your talking about the protocol I'll use to connect the SCADA to Android app, the answer would be HTTP (since I understood from your answer that it's easier).

To summarize the main points:

1. I need to have experience in network applications and HTTP protocol.

2. LAN may be easier somehow.

 Any more advice?

Comment: Well, then you'll be basically building a gateway between SIMPPI and HTTP. LAN will be easier because you can use [Multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) to find the server. From a *programming* perspective, there's little difference otherwise. To make an application available over the Internet, you need more *infrastructure* (as in domain names/IP addresses/servers/administration) though.